# What is the simplest way to create a file?

Tags: java, file, file-io, directory

This doesn't seem to create a file or folder. Why?

```
import java.io.*;
public class file1
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {

    File text1 = new File("C:/text1.txt");
    File dir1 = new File("C:/dir");
}
```

This one below does create a file.

```
import java.io.*;
public class file3
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    try
    {
    FileWriter text1 = new FileWriter("C:/text.txt");
     FileWriter dir = new FileWriter("C:/dir");
}
catch(Exception e){}

    }
}
```

However, the directory seems to have a strange unusable icon.

What can I do to create a directory.
What are other simple methods to create files and folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surprisingly, the `File` class does not represent a file.  It actually represents a pathname for a file ... that may or may not exist.

To create a file in Java, you need to open it for output; e.g.

```
    File text1 = new File("C:/text1.txt");
    FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(text1);  // The file is created 
                                                        // here ... if it doesn't 
                                                        // exist already.
    // then write to the file and close it.
```

or you could do this - `new FileOutputStream("C:/text1.txt")`.  In both cases, an existing file will be truncated ... unless you use the `FileOutputStream` with a boolean parameter that says open for appending.

If you want to create a file without writing any data to it, you could also do this:

```
    File text1 = new File("C:/text1.txt");
    text1.createNewFile();
```

However, that will only create a new file if the file didn't already exist.

To create a directory in Java, use the `File.mkdir()` or `File.mkdirs()` methods.

**UPDATE**

You commented:

> I tried `File dir = new File("C:/dir1").mkdir();` it says incompatible types.

That is right.  The `mkdir()` method returns a `boolean` to say whether or not it created the directory.  What you need to write is something like this:

```
    File dir = new File("C:/dir1");
    if (dir.mkdir()) {
        System.out.println("I created it"); 
    }
```

Always READ THE JAVADOCS before using a method or class you are not familiar with!

---

A couple more things you need to know:

- The best way to deal with the problem of making sure a file gets closed is to do something like this:

  ```
      try (FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(text1)) {
          // now write to it
      }
  ```

  The stream `os` will be closed automatically when the block exits.
- It is usually "bad practice" to catch `Exception`.  It is *always* "bad practice" to catch `Exception` and do nothing in the handler.  This kind of this *hides the evidence* of bugs, and makes your code unpredictable and hard to debug.

Comment: Thanks. I tried  File dir = new File("C:/dir1").mkdir(); it says incompatible types. Found boolean, but expected java.io.File.

Comment: Is catch(IOException e){System.out.print("bug");} OK?

Comment: Better.  Better still is `catch(IOException e){System.out.print("unexpected exception: " + e);}`

Comment: OK. Thanks. But I am still having trouble creating a directory.

Comment: Ah. Thanks. I also tried: File dir = new File("C:/dir1");
    dir.mkdir(); That worked too.

Answer (score 0):

If you're creating a directory with `File`, you want this:

```
new File("C:/dir").mkdirs();
```

Comment: I tried File dir = new File("C:/dir1").mkdir();but igives an error.Found boolean but expected java.io.File

Comment: Try just the line, as I wrote it, without the File dir = part.

Comment: Thaks a lot. I did new File("C:/dir2").mkdirs(); And it created the directory dir2. Why does    File dir2 = new File("C:/dir2").mkdirs(); not work?

Answer (score 0):

For creating directory you can use :

```
if(!text1.exists()){
     text1.mkdir();
}
```

and for creating file use:

```
if(!text1.exists()){
    try {
        text1.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. text1.exists where? How do I create it at C:/ ?

Comment: Here `text1` is variable from your code ` File text1 = new File("C:/text1.txt");`. `exists()` is method of file, read about that in docs.

Comment: I am having al little trouble understanding like this. If you could please give the full code that's inside the try block - 2lines, 4lines, whatever it takes.